# Pull from current origin without explicit typing

Tags: git, git-bash

Is there a shortcut to pull from the current branch without explicit calling it.

E.g. I've checked out a branch: `git checkout mybranch`

To pull from the branch I use `git pull origin mybranch`. Is it possible to skip the `origin mybranch` part? The problem is, that our branches have quite long names like `b_searchsystem_grid`.

Maybe something like `git pull origin .` (. for current branch).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

After you establish the correct defaults, you can run just `git pull` with no arguments, though I recommend you split it into `git fetch && git merge` if that's what you intend.

## Long

First, remember that `git pull` just means: *Run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command.*  The second command defaults to `git merge`, but you can choose `git rebase` instead.

The `git fetch` command needs to know two things:

- Fetch from where?

  Importantly, there is a default.  The default is the *remote* associated with the current branch, based on its *upstream*.  Both of these are defined below.
- Fetch what?

  There is a default here too.  Running `git fetch` with no arguments means "fetch everything", which is what you will usually want.  When `git pull` runs `git fetch`, it adds some arguments to limit what gets fetched, which may make *this* fetch slightly faster, but make future fetches slightly slower in the process.  (Pay now, or pay later, but since the payment is generally just fractions of seconds, who cares?)

The `git merge` or `git rebase` command needs to know at least one thing:

- What should we merge, or rebase upon?

And here, too, there is a default.  The default is the *upstream*.  When you use `git pull` to run the second Git command, it fiddles with this somewhat, but the effect is basically the same, so that you can just run the two Git commands yourself.

#### Remotes

Any Git repository can have any number of what Git calls *remotes*.  A remote is primarily a short name for a URL, which acts like a phone number at which some other Git repository can be reached.  The most common remote name is `origin`.

When you run `git clone` to make an initial clone of some other Git repository, you tell `git clone` how to reach the other Git, giving it a URL.  The `clone` step *saves* that URL under the name `origin`.<sup>1</sup>  Hence `origin` becomes the easy way to mention that other Git.

#### Each branch can have one single *upstream*

The *upstream* of a branch is made of two parts:

- the name of a remote, and
- the name of a branch on that other Git.

Typically we just lump these two together, so that the upstream of branch *`B`* is `origin/B`.  **Note that creating a local branch from a remote-tracking name sets the upstream automatically, so that you rarely have to do this at all.**<sup>2</sup>

To set or change the upstream of any given branch, you can use any of several commands:

- `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/branch branch` (this sets the upstream of *`branch`* to `origin/branch`)
- `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/branch` (this sets the upstream of the *current* branch, whatever you have checked out, to `origin/branch`)

  **This is usually the one you should use if you have not just created the branch.**  Typically you'll be on the branch, and it will be time to set its upstream, so you can now set it.
- `git push -u origin branch`

  **This is what you should use if you've just created the branch.**  If you just created the branch, so that there is no `origin/branch` at all, you have to first *create* the name *`branch`* in the other Git, which you do with `git push`.  Now that it exists, and you also have `origin/branch`, *now* you can set the upstream.  Using `git push -u` will do both at the same time, as a short-cut, and it has the side effect of making `git push` know that you *meant* to create the branch in the other Git, so it skips a bunch of annoying error messages as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>You can choose another name, but people rarely do.

<sup>2</sup>Consider the following sequence:

```
git clone <url>        # creates repository, adds the remote, fetches,
                       # and checks out master based on origin/master

cd <repository>        # enter repo so that you can work in it

git checkout develop   # creates develop based on origin/develop
```

The `git clone` step created your `master` branch by running, in effect, `git checkout master`.  That made `master` have an upstream, namely `origin/master`.  The `git checkout develop` step does the same thing: finds `origin/develop`, uses that to make a *new* branch name `develop` as *your* `develop`, and sets your `develop` to have `origin/develop` as its upstream.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `git pull` and have it imply origin if you did `git push -u origin <branch>` once it'll make all future git pulls based on origin by setting your upstream remote.

Comment: Don't pass `-u` to `git pull` (where it means `--update-head-ok`); do pass it to `git push` (where it means `--set-upstream`).

Comment: yep, my bad I meant push

Answer (score 2):

I think it's important to not just memorize the command, but to also understand the reason behind this.

Git branches can have an "upstream branch" set, which is the corresponding branch to your local branch on a remote. This upstream branch has to be explicitly declared, because you might have multiple remotes. In that case, git would not know where to push or pull from to when you do `git push` or `git pull`.

You can list the upstream branches of your branches:

```
$ git branch -vv
* testbranch           271404b commit message
  master               ac7a302 [origin/master] add foo
```

Here you see that the `testbranch` branch does not have an upstream branch, so git would not know where to push/pull from. However, the master branch does have an upstream branch (`origin/master`), so git does know what to do when we type `git pull`.

There are a few ways we can set the upstream branch:

- `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/branchname`
- `git branch -u origin/branchname` (just a shorthand)
- `git push -u origin branchname` (often more convenient)

Comment: Don't use `git branch --set-upstream`, use `git branch --set-upstream-to` (first introduced in Git 1.8.0). The problem is that the [original verb was mis-specified](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0c37383f2ecfce28f67dbc49704ab3755d41eed0/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.0.txt#L42-L47).

Comment: thanks, fixed! I added the shorter -u option too, I didn't see that in the help message but it does work.

Comment: Yeah, it—the `-u` short version—is in the longer documentation (and the release note lines I linked to above). Since it's not so commonly needed, I tend to use the spelled-out one. It might be nice if they took out the `--set-upstream` verb here since it acts so badly :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
```

For git 2.22+:

```
git pull origin $(git branch --show-current)
```